# Passing mutiple arguments with AJAX. Values come from DIV

Tags: ajax

I am trying to pass two arguments thought ajax. The variables I am pulling from are in a div and are done on the fly. I can easily pass the date_time but I need to be able to pass a variable "id" also. The date is in an array that is being loaded and changes. The ID does not change for this page.

This is the javascript. Below that will be my div. All attempts to append this have failed. Any ideas?

```
<div class='letter' width=600  date_time=\"$date_time\" id=\"$id\">
....doing stuff here.....
</div>

function OnScrollLetters () {  var div = document.getElementById ("userLetter");
   var info = document.getElementById ("info");
   if(div.scrollTop == (div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight))
   {    
      $('div#loadMoreComments').show();
      $.ajax({
         url: "get_letters_for_profile_scroll.php?lastComment="+ $(".letter:last").attr('date_time'),
         success: function(html) {
            if(html){       
               $("#userLetter").append(html);
               $('div#loadMoreComments').hide();
            }else{
               $('div#loadMoreComments').replaceWith("<center><h1 style='color:red'>End of Letters</h1></center>");
            }
         }
      });
   }
}
```

This is my div.

```
<div class='letter' width=600  date_time=\"$date_time\" id=\"$id\">
....doing stuff here.....
</div>
```

Comment: which div? Can you please review your question and clear your code.

Comment: The div in the top part. It didnt allow me to post that.

div class='letter' width=600 date_time=\"$date_time\" id=\"$id\">
 ....doing stuff here..... 
/div

Comment: In my div I am just loading an array that displays the output.

url: "get_letters_for_profile_scroll.php?lastComment="+ $(".letter:last").attr('date_time')+"&id"+$(".letter:last").attr('id'),

I would think this would have worked but it didnt.

Comment: What do you get? Try place a = between parameter name and value `..."&id="+$(".letter:last").attr('id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try place a "=" between parameter name and value

```
..."&id="+$(".letter:last").attr('id')
```